# skimage: get longest filled axis length

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have pictures of some root vegetables from which I would like to extract their length and width. I have already segmented the root out from the picture using threshold-based segmentation. When I use **measure.regionprops_table**, I get a lot of interference from the small roots and twigs, which I would like to remove.

Here is an example image: [Segmented image of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGpit.png)

The red lines in the above figure show the length and width I want to extract, while the blue lines show the values I get. The blue lines stetch the farthest extent of the filled holes, which artificially inflates the root size.

One idea was to extract out the min/max_row and min/max_col based on the longest continuous stretch of filled holes in the image, moving along either X or Y axis, without encountering any non-filled holes. Is there a function for that? If not, how do I encode it?

The unmodified segmented image is here: [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB1dI.png)

Here is the code I'm using for parsing:

```
#Import modules
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.util import random_noise
from skimage import feature, data, morphology
from skimage.exposure import histogram
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

#Get image and convert to grayscale
image = mpimg.imread(f'{name}')
imgplot = plt.imshow(image)    
grayscale = rgb2gray (image)

#Segmentation using threshold values
hist, hist_centers = histogram(grayscale)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))
axes[0].imshow(grayscale, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
axes[0].axis('off')
axes[1].plot(hist_centers, hist, lw=2)
axes[1].set_title('histogram of gray values')

#Fill holes and remove coins
fillh = ndi.binary_fill_holes(grayscale<0.5)
fillh2 = morphology.remove_small_objects(fillh, 100000)

#Get properties
fill_label = label(fillh2)
props = regionprops_table(fill_label,properties=('minor_axis_length', 'major_axis_length', 'bbox', 'euler_number'))
pd.DataFrame(props)

#Function to calculate largest component
def getLargestCC(segmentlabel):    
    assert( segmentlabel.max() != 0 ) # assume at least 1 CC
    largestCC = segmentlabel == np.argmax(np.bincount(segmentlabel.flat)[1:])+1
    return largestCC
largest = getLargestCC(fill_label)
larlabel = label(largest)

#Get properties again
props = regionprops_table(larlabel,properties=('minor_axis_length', 'major_axis_length', 'bbox', 'euler_number'))
pd.DataFrame(props)
```

Comment: Apply a binary opening to your mask, with a disk structuring element. This will remove the twigs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - Thank you! That worked perfectly!